# Deduction of auto doesn't work when implemented as Lambda. Error: before deduction of 'auto'

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14

Here I've implemented a templated function and a templated Lambda. I've started exploring C++14 features and not sure what's wrong with the following lambda. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template<class T = std::mt19937, std::size_t N = T::state_size>
auto MersenneEngine() {
    return T(N);
}

template<class T = std::mt19937, std::size_t N = T::state_size>
auto MersenneEngineLambda = []() {
    return T(N);
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::cout << MersenneEngine<std::mt19937>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << MersenneEngineLambda<std::mt19937>() << std::endl; // Compilation error : error: use of 'MersenneEngineLambda<std::mersenne_twister_engine...before deduction of 'auto'
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the complete code http://ideone.com/lveJRN

Comment: No issues compiling the code with gcc 6.1.1. There's nothing wrong with the shown code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, interesting. I've added a link to ideone, not sure if it is the compiler version that ideone is using, maybe

Comment: That's GCC 5.1, but GCC docs show no indication of any C++14 features missing then. I notice that the code you linked to is not the code you showed us. GCC 5.1 won't accept either of them, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit apologies, I've pasted the code shown above

Comment: Bugs in GCC surrounding this feature are not unprecedented - http://stackoverflow.com/q/33438813/560648 If I were trying to procrastinate, I'd figure out which version fixed this then examine its changelog to get you a bug number. But the solution is "upgrade".

Answer (score 4):

The code is fine.

You are witnessing a bug in your version of GCC (5.1). This is not highly surprising given that variable templates were brand new in GCC 5.

Empirically, it was fixed either in or before GCC 6.1.1.

*[Bug 67041](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67041) (and, more directly, its dupe [bug 67350](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67350)) looks potentially relevant.*

Comment: You did procrastinate for 3 minutes! xD

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: It's only procrastinating if there was something else I was supposed to do ;)